# spring security form login method deprecated

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a security configuration below;

```
SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain
        (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    http.formLogin();
    http.httpBasic();
    return http.build();
}
```

it says  `http.formLogin();`
and  `http.httpBasic();`
deprecated.

This simple thing is already made a complex topic by spring and top of that when I managed to find a working code, this time, it is deprecated :(

How can I replace this code in new fluent way?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Migration guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/index.html), you have to use [Lambda DSL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/migration-7/configuration.html) on configuration part of `SecurityFilterChain` .

By the way you current configuration have to be as next one:

```
  SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http.authorizeHttpRequests(request -> {
      request.anyRequest().authenticated();
    })
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
    
  }
```

To have more understanding about it please read/check linked above references.